# Python 'expected an indented block' error?

Tags: python-3.x

At first the it expected an indent at the end of the docstring, and when i put that in it then expects an indent on line 28, and then when I indent there as well it expects it on line 36 as shown.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/72g0I.png

Would really appreciate some help, thank you.

Comment: Honestly, your indentation is a mess. Please learn first how to properly indent Python code

Comment: Are you aware that Python is indentation based?

Comment: Please do not link to pictures of code – [edit] your question to include the code as code-formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of indentation errors on your code.

Here is the code with indentation

```
def nr_numberic(f, epsilon, start, iters, tol):
  x = start
  for i in range(iters):
      fx_i = f(x)
      derivative_i = 1.0 * (f(x + epsilon) - f(x)) / epsilon
      if derivative_i == 0:
         return None
      x = x - 1.0 * fx_i / derivative_i
      if abs(f(x)) < tol:
         return x
      None



f = lambda x: x**2 + 5*x +8

print(nr_numberic(f,0.001,10,100, 1e-5))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if derivate_i = 0:
    return None
```

Comment: It will also throw error for line 43. You will have to check the syntax properly.

Comment: That's hardly the only indentation issue, and in fact this specific one will just be *another* SyntaxError without fixing the overall indentation.

Comment: Yes. you are right!